# How to trigger on textarea change on javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am having trouble trigger the on textarea change. The problem I have is that the event only triggers when I manually type in the text area (aka when the text area is in focus).

What I really is for the `btnSpeak.click()` to be called when the textarea is changed while being out of focus.

```
$('#chat').bind('input propertychange',function(){
    btnSpeak.click();
});
```

The code below shows my chat app in which the textarea called `$chat` is populated with data(strings).

```
socket.on('new message', function (data) {
    $chat.append(data);

});
```

So the whole idea is that when the message is sent, textarea will be populated and finally javascript will detect textarea change and perform a `btnSpeak.click()`.

Comment: `$chat.append(data).trigger("input")`?

Comment: Is this socket.io? You should probably mention that.

Comment: @nnnnnn post ur comment as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer per comment from @nnnnnn!:
    $chat.append(data).trigger("input")

Answer (score 0):

Ummm i think i have a sloution for this ..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('textarea').trigger('change');
});
```

But this will only trigger if the change event was added through jQuery. 
If not then try the following snippet

```
$('textarea').get(0).change();
```